# NSTableView - tab between rows with text fields

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview, nstextfield

I have a table view with a single column, that column is made up of a number of one single text field.  I want to be able to tab from cell to cell.

So far, I am detecting the tab key press as follows;

```
override func controlTextDidEndEditing(obj: NSNotification) {

    let lastRow = self.customFieldsTableView.numberOfRows
    let lastCol = self.customFieldsTableView.numberOfColumns

    let selectedRow = self.customFieldsTableView.selectedRow
    let selectedColumn = self.customFieldsTableView.selectedColumn

    let userInfo = obj.userInfo
    let textMovement = userInfo!["NSTextMovement"] as! NSNumber

    if textMovement == NSTabTextMovement {
        if (selectedRow != lastRow - 1){
            self.customFieldsTableView.selectRowIndexes(NSIndexSet(index: selectedRow   ), byExtendingSelection: false)
            self.customFieldsTableView.editColumn(0, row: selectedRow + 1, withEvent: nil, select: true)
        }
    } else if textMovement == NSReturnTextMovement {
        debugPrint("Return")
    }
```

My thinking here was that I could detect the tab, then tell the tableview to move onto the next view, but it's not working.  Tabbing either does nothing or moves onto the next key view.

What am I missing?

Edit: I am able to intercept the tab within this function, but selectedRow is sometimes -1 (nil)